# Query from union of joins

Tags: sql

I have been doing sql exercises from [sql-ex.ru site](http://sql-ex.ru/) and stumbled into one that I can't make correct.

Here it is:

> Find the model number of the product (PC, laptop, or printer) with the
>   highest price.
>
> Result set: model.

Database schema is explained [here](http://sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_1). I will just put its diagram here:

[image: Database schema diagram]

I came up with this solution:

```
with model_price(model,price) as (
select model,price 
from PC

union

select model,price 
from Laptop

union

select model,price 
from Printer
)

select model
from model_price
where price >= all(select price from model_price)
```

The system outputs the following result:

```
Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database.
* Wrong number of records (less by 2)
```

The system provides the answer for the `main database`. But I don't know what the checking database is and can't determine what is wrong by executing subqueries separately and looking where I make mistake.

So I'm asking here in the hope that you can notice what I do wrong. This task is of level 2 (quite simple), so it should be something trivial that I'm missing.

<sub>About sql engine: [`Now we use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on the rating stages, and MySQL 5.5.11, PostgreSQL 9.0, and Oracle Database 11g on the learn stage in addition.`](http://sql-ex.ru/#ref_sint)
So I don't know which engine exactly they use to asses this exercise.</sub>

Comment: @ruakh [Link to the exercise](http://sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php?LN=24). But to open it one should be registered on the site.

Comment: @ruakh You are right about rudundancy of join. I was just sloppy.

Comment: @ruakh I have edited the answer with joins removed

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try with the following. It's ANSI-Standard SQL, so you don't have to worry, which RDBMS is used.

```
SELECT
model 
FROM
(
SELECT
model, price
FROM
pc
UNION ALL
SELECT
model, price
FROM
printer
UNION ALL
SELECT
model, price
FROM
laptop
) sq 
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM (
  SELECT
  model, price
  FROM
  pc
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  model, price
  FROM
  printer
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  model, price
  FROM
  laptop
) sq2
)
```

Comment: Your query returns 4 columns instead of one and much more rows (should be one).

Comment: You query returned `1200.0000`, should be `1750`. :(

Comment: What is wrong is that `model` should be returned, not `max(price)`!

Comment: Oh, okay, now I get it. Corrected it.

Comment: This query gave correct result for first DB, but wrong result for the second: `Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database.
* Wrong number of records (more by 1)` Notice that the number of missing rows is different!

Comment: Again, this query gives `more by 1` and my query (with `union all`) gives `less by 2`. To me they look the same. I'm not getting why the results are different.

Comment: This exercise is actually pretty basic. So I wouldn't doubt the query. But may it be, that the question is for the max price for each producttype?

Comment: I found how to make you query valid! The solution is to add `distinct` keyword after first select.

Comment: What I don't understand is why it produces different results with my query (which uses `with` syntax).

Comment: No, I copied your query and added `distict` after the first `SELECT`.

Comment: I found the culprit. It is `all` syntax that I used. My query works if I use `where price = (select max(price) ...` insetad of `where price >= all ...`

Comment: I mean, when you tried again now with your query (with `with` syntax).

Comment: My query started working when I changed `all` to `max` in subquery. I do not need `distinct` in my query as it is performed by `union` command.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use subquery with `max` function instead of comparing with `all`:

```
with model_price(model,price) as (
select model,price 
from PC

union

select model,price 
from Laptop

union

select model,price 
from Printer
)

select model
from model_price
where price = (select max(price) from model_price)
```

No need for `distinct` keyword as `union` returns unique rows.

Thanks to **tombom** who helped me find this.

The solution with `all` doesn't work, as `price` column may have `NULL` values, and comparing to `NULL` produces `false`, which make the whole result for `all` `false`, while using `max` just searches for he maximum price ignoring `NULL`s. This I learned by asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028334/value-allselect-v2-produces-different-results-from-value-select-max).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT model, price FROM (
  (SELECT model, price FROM pc ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1)
    /* your database may use a TOP 1 syntax for the LIMIT queries */
   UNION ALL
  (SELECT model, price FROM laptop ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1)
   UNION ALL
  (SELECT model, price FROM printer ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1)
 ) AS subquery_name_required
 ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If the price field is indexed (which it should be for a query like this), the ORDER/LIMIT (or equivalent TOP) will run very fast as the DB plucks the highest price from the table.

Note: In a database that supports **table inheritance** (or can be kludged to support something like it with discriminator columns), refactoring the common columns into a single table has a lot to say for it! Imagine if you start selling scaners, monitors, SSDs, etc.—what a nightmare!

**[EDIT to show ties]**

```
SELECT model, price FROM (
  SELECT model, price FROM 
    (SELECT model, price, rank() OVER (ORDER BY price DESC) AS r FROM pc) AS s1
    WHERE r=1
    /* your database may not yet support windowing queries;
      in that case you probably have to compare to MAX,
      which may mean an extra pass through every table. */
   UNION ALL
  SELECT model, price FROM 
    (SELECT model, price, rank() OVER (ORDER BY price DESC) AS r FROM laptop) AS s2
    WHERE r=1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT model, price FROM 
    (SELECT model, price, rank() OVER (ORDER BY price DESC) AS r FROM printer) AS s3
    WHERE r=1
 ) AS subquery_name_required
 ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I don't have enough experience with this sort of windowing to know if an index on `price` will be scanned just as far as necessary. I hope so. Conceptually that shouldn't be more difficult than the `LIMIT 1`, just have to recognize that it's a trickier but similar query.

Comment: What if there are 2 models with the highest price in PC table?

Comment: You will get an arbitrary result in case of a tie, either within or across types of product, one of the correct items but which one is not even guaranteed consistent from one execution to the next. What would you _want_ to use as a tie-breaker?

Comment: I don't know, but it seems that the site I'm performing exercies at is expecting all the models with the highest price.

Comment: Not a problem if the database supports windowing functions. Will edit answer.

Comment: I've already found what was making my solution in the questing wrong. If I use `where price = (select max(price) from model_price)` instead of `where price >= all(select price from model_price)` the result is correct. May be you know why?

Comment: No, I would think those would give the same result. But if your database supports windowing, try comparing the execution plans with `EXPLAIN`; I think you will see very different efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I think i caught the problem: you use `union` with models and price: if you have two different products (code) with the same price (the max) and model you end giving only one row (`union` instead `union all` eliminates the duplicates). 
The result set is the correct, yes, but in the validation they say that you gave only one row instead of two

Comment: I'll give it a try. So I execute the query with `union all` instead of `union`.

Comment: I mean that the result is wrong again :) `Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database.
* Wrong number of records (less by 2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tab1 as
(
        /* laptop */
        (
            SELECT 1 model, 2000 price FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 model, 2250 price FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 model, 2500 price FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 model, 2550 price FROM DUAL           -- <---- the highest value
        )
        UNION ALL
        /* printer */
        (
            SELECT 5 model, 500  price FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 6 model, 750  price FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 7 model, 1000 price FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 8 model, 1250 price FROM DUAL
        )
        UNION ALL
        /* pc */
        (
            SELECT 9  model, 1000 price FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 10 model, 1250 price FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 11 model, 1500 price FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 12 model, 1750 price FROM DUAL
        )
)
SELECT  model
FROM    tab1
WHERE   price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM tab1);
```

Comment: Thanks! First, you should use `SELECT distinct  model` as there may be several `models` with highest price, or better `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. Then this query will produce correct result (accoring to the checking system of the site). Still, I don't understand why `price > (SELECT price FROM tab1)` produces wrong results.

Comment: 1) If you have several product with the highest price they should be selected, i.e.: model: 4, price 1000 and model: 5, price 1000. That is because: "It is assumed that model numbers in the Product table are unique"
2) You cannot use "price >" because there will be nothing to select . You can use "price >=" because evaluation leads to the biggest number.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I meant `price >= all (...` (as I typed in the question).

Answer (score 0):

```
select model 
from (Select model, price from pc
where price = (select max(price) from pc)
union
Select model, price from laptop
where price = (select max(price) from laptop)
union
Select model, price from printer
where price = (select max(price) from printer)
) as A
where price = (
select max(price) from (
Select model, price from pc
where price = (select max(price) from pc)
union
Select model, price from laptop
where price = (select max(price) from laptop)
union
Select model, price from printer
where price = (select max(price) from printer)
) as B
)
```