# value >= all(select v2 ...) produces different results from value = (select max(v2) ...)

Tags: sql

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026651/query-from-union-of-joins/17027784?noredirect=1#comment24611997_17027784) I asked the question about not working query.

Accidentally (with the help of one answer) I found how to make the solution right. The problem is that I don't understand why they produce different results.

So, the database has this schema:

[image]

And I'm searching for all the models from `PC`, `Printer` and `Laptop` with the **highest** price. All these tables may have non-unique `model` column, as items with different `code` may have the same model.

My original solution was:

```
with model_price(model,price) as (
select model,price 
from PC

union

select model,price 
from Laptop

union

select model,price 
from Printer
)

select model
from model_price
where price >= all(select price from model_price)
```

It gave wrong result - the system returned `* Wrong number of records (less by 2)`.

The corrected solution which works is this:

```
with model_price(model,price) as (
select model,price 
from PC

union

select model,price 
from Laptop

union

select model,price 
from Printer
)

select model
from model_price
where price = (select max(price) from model_price)
```

So, why the solution with `all` produces different result?

---

<sub>About sql engine: [`Now we use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on the rating stages, and MySQL 5.5.11, PostgreSQL 9.0, and Oracle Database 11g on the learn stage in addition.`](http://sql-ex.ru/#ref_sint)
So I don't know which engine exactly they use to asses this exercise.</sub>

Comment: Any `NULL`s in the data? `select 1 where 1 >= ALL (select null union select 0)` returns no rows.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know data for the second database (this is made intentionally for those who make exercises don't cheat). I can't even see the result for the queries on the second DB, only abstracts what is wrong, e.g. `* Wrong number of records (less by 2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create table t (f int null);

select 1 where 1 >= (select max(f) from t); -- 1
select 1 where 1 >= all(select f from t);   -- 2

insert into t values (null), (0);

select 1 where 1 >= (select max(f) from t); -- 3
select 1 where 1 >= all(select f from t);   -- 4
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d1b1/1

The first `select` returns nothing, the second `select` returns `1`.

`MAX` returns a scalar value. If no rows exist, `MAX` returns `NULL`. `1 >= NULL` is not true on line 1. On the other hand, `1 >= all f`s is true, because there are no `f`s at all for which the condition is *not* true.

The third `select` returns `1`, the fourth `select` returns nothing.

`MAX`, like all aggregate functions, ignores `NULL`s. `MAX(f)` is 0 on line 3, and `1 >= 0` is true. `ALL` doesn't: it evaluates `1 >= NULL AND 1 >= 0` on line 4, which is not true.

Comment: Note that you could use `ISNULL` (aka `ISNULL(price, 0)`) if you want to use `ALL` for another reason.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably THE exercise I should learn from this task! So, `NULL` is not promoted to `0` automatically while being compared.

Comment: Right, and if it's possible for all the field values to be negative, treating `NULL` as `0` might even be very wrong, so it's probably a good thing that the database doesn't do that automatically. This can make sense even for a field "price", if you've got special "discount" articles.

Comment: @ovgolovin I've updated my answer, I forgot about another difference. It may or may not be relevant for you.